# Change stream format of command line sp-sc (Sopcast) utility

Tags: streaming, encoding, video-streaming, transcode, sopcast

I am using the command line version of Sopcast under Ubuntu 14.04. I am using it like sp-sc sop://address port port. This takes the P2P stream and re-transmits it as an live ASF stream. I usually open one channel with sp-sc and connect to it via VLC. I am curious if there is any command line argument to change the ASF to MP4 or something that can play directly in a browser (so this way I retransmit the P2P stream as a HTTP MPEG4 stream to web flash player clients). Or will I need ffmpeg to do this (I have no idea how to real-time re-encode with ffmped, and it may also hog my CPU, as it is already being killed by the numerous P2P connections the Sopcast client makes).